# Cannot select from replication database view

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My `org` has 2 snowflake accounts in different regions. Let's name them `a` (primary) and `b` (secondary). The Org admin enabled replication from account `org.a` => `org.b`. The account admin on `a` created a database called `stuff_to_share` and enabled replication to account `org.b`. He also created a schema `all` and a view called `snapshot` which is pulling the data from a Database called `all`.

```sql
create database stuff_to_share;
create schema all;
create view snapshot as
  select * from all.fact.snapshot
```

On my side, I've created a DB from the replication

```sql
create database stuff_to_share as
  replica of org.a.stuff_to_share;
```

I can see the view, I can run `desc view stuff_to_share.all.snapshot` but when I try to run a `select` I get an `SQL Compilation Error` like below:

[image]

I've found [this article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/SQL-compilation-error-Failure-during-expansion-of-view-mySecureView) but cannot understand the recommendations. It says to

> 1. Avoid using the fully qualified name for the secure View in the Primary database.

How am I supposed to get data from a different DB in a view then?

> 2. Use the same name as that of the Primary database when creating the Secondary database.

I'm guessing this refers to `stuff_to_share` which is the same on both accounts.

Please help.

Comment: `all.fact.snapshot` is DB `all` schema `fact` table `snapshot` so on you side you would need to apply suggestion #2 have a db all, schema fact, and table snapshot for the FQN to work. Or just use relative names, but then you run the risk of using a view via it FQN name, but it looks in the current DB/SCHEMA.. all rahter messy. I would be inclined to think a replicate should replicate everything if it is to be useful as a hot/warm swap target, other all the little difference just like this will break things, when you least need it.

Comment: A view is just a definition for the query, it doesn't actually have any data unless you run it. Since your view gets data from a different database that's not replicated you get this issue.

Comment: How would I have to go about getting that data? We can't replicate the underlying DB as it contains other sensible data and can't create a share because it's from another region.

Comment: What is the concern with replicating the underlying DB?  I understand you feel you have sensitive data in there, but you could easily lock that down on your replica account in the same (or better) manner than you have it on your primary account, right?

Comment: Your other option could be to use a clone, instead of a view, but then you'd have to re-clone and re-replicate that data every time you update the underlying table, which would be a bit more cumbersome.

Comment: @MikeWalton I think I've heard about the clone option from other team members but it didn't click at the time. I will try to request the original DB be replicated but I think they are also concerned on the resource usage.

Comment: Clones are called zero-copy clones for a reason.  They do not take any storage or compute to create.  However, that data will need to replicate to your secondary, so you may want to only clone the tables that you actually need to replicate.